# passing conditional spring mvc parameters into javascript url function

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

I have a javascript calendar control in a spring mvc application.  When the user clicks on a `date` in the calendar control, the user is redirected to a detail page for that date.  The problem is that I want to pass other parameters in the url in addition to just the `date`.  How do I add other parameters to the url in the javascript functionality?

Here is the javascript for creating the url with only the `date` as a parameter:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#dayPicker").datepicker({
                            firstDay: 1,
                            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                            defaultDate: new Date(${calendar.dayMillis}),
                            onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
                                window.location = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendar?day=" + encodeURIComponent(dateText);
                                }
                        });
                    });
        </script>
```

For illustration, here is the code for generating a url including two other optional parameters (`pid` and `eid`) elsewhere in the JSP:

```
            <c:url var="previousLink" value="/calendar">
                <c:param name="day" value="${calendar.previousDay}" />
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${pid!=null}">
                        <c:param name="pid" value="${pid}" />
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise></c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${eid!=null}">
                        <c:param name="eid" value="${eid}"></c:param>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </c:url>
            <a href="${previousLink}">Previous</a>
```

How do I alter the javascript above so that it adds parameters for `pid` and `eid` **if and only if** either `pid` or `eid` is `not null`?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by concatenating the URL parameters separated by the `&` character:

```
var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendar?day=" + encodeURIComponent(dateText);

if (pid) {
    url += "&pid=" + encodeURIComponent(pid);
}

if (eid) {
    url += "&eid=" + encodeURIComponent(eid);
}

window.location = url;
```

Comment: +1 Thank you.  But your code is adding a `#` sign to the end of the url so it looks like this: `/calendar?day=2014-03-10&pid=1#` . Is there some way to alter your code so it does not leave a `#` sign at the end?

Comment: Im glad I could help, the `#` is the bookmark sign and it can be safely ignored as it does not get sent to the server on POST/GET. Somehow encodeURIComponent seems to be adding it

Comment: I am testing the code, and it turns out that the following two lines cause the link to never change the value of the date parameter: `if (pid) {url += "&pid=" + encodeURIComponent(pid);}` , 
`if (eid) {url += "&eid=" + encodeURIComponent(eid);}` . When I remove these 2 lines, the rest of your suggested code lets me change dates, but the `eid` and `pid` parameters are not added to the url.  How can I fix this?

Comment: The code in my posting sets the url when a user clicks on a calendar day in the jquery datepicker tool at this link: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Noticing your comments about pid and eid not working, it's most likely that you need to add the jquery brackets to get the pid and eid. So it would be like this:

```js
var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendar?day=" + encodeURIComponent(dateText);

if (${pid!=null}) {
    url += "&pid=" + encodeURIComponent(${pid});
}

if (${eid!=null}) {
    url += "&eid=" + encodeURIComponent(${eid});
}

window.location = url;
```

Also, if you are not actually adding the eid or pid to the model when it is 'null', it wouldn't actually be null, so you may not get the desired functionality either. If you are actually adding eid and pid to the model as 'null' then the above should be fine. However, if when eid and pid are null, you just leave them out of the model all together, you would need to check it as such:

```js
var url = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendar?day=" + encodeURIComponent(dateText);

if (${! empty pid}) {
    url += "&pid=" + encodeURIComponent(${pid});
}

if (${! empty eid}) {
    url += "&eid=" + encodeURIComponent(${eid});
}

window.location = url;
```